# Does maven-release-plugin push tags to remote Git repository?

Tags: git, maven-2, tags, release-management, maven-release-plugin

When using the maven-release-plugin with Git, mvn release:prepare happily tags the release in the local repository.  I'd expect mvn release:perform to push the tags to the remote repository, but this doesn't *seem* to happen.

Am I mistaken?

If not, is there an option to enable pushing release tags to the remote repository?

Comment: Does your Git server give permission to push the tag?
On a Gerrit server I needed "Forge Committer" permission when the Jenkins userid was different from the userid being used to push.

Comment: Interesting question, but 5 years on I can't remember!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, `release-prepare` seems to be pushing three times:

1. After committing the POM updated to the new release version, it's running `git push` with no arguments, to push that commit.
2. After tagging, it's running `git push origin <tagname>`, which is what should push the tag.
3. After committing the POM updated to the new snapshot version, it's running `git push` with no arguments again.

Given that it's explicitly specifying `origin` for the tag push, it may only successfully push the tags if your git-remote alias is actually called `origin`.
To see what yours are called, run `git remote -v`.

Note also that `git push` without arguments may default to something other than `origin`, depending on your repository config - i.e. it may have been trying to push commits to one place and tags to another. See here for where those defaults come from:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#REMOTES

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  This behaviour seems inconsistent and unhelpful to me.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I agree that it should not push during `relese:prepare`. What happened to me is that the `release:prepare` worked fine, but the `release:perform` failed because the `scm` eddres in the pom-file was wrong. So I actually tagged a build with a broken `pom.xml`. IMO, given the distributed nature of git, it would make more sense to push at the very end of this process. Am I wrong?